# Convert append reading of a text to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I just read a data series in a .txt  file and pythons saves it as text like this [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raGuG.png)

I need to convert it to datetime because I need to resample it and some other information related with each datetime.

I used this code to read my data

```
Dia=[]
TemperaturaMin=[]
TemperaturaHora=[]
Confiabilidad=[]

f=open(TablasTorre[0]+ '.txt', 'r')
datos=f.readlines()

for i in datos:
    Dia.append(i[0:19])
    TemperaturaMin.append(i[20:28])
    Confiabilidad.append(i[35:40])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you don't know what is your datetime format, you can use `dateutil`:

```
from dateutil import parser
my_datetime = parser.parse("12/03/2015 00:00:00.000")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can read a string of a date into a `datetime` object using `datetime.datetime.strptime`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2016-02-17 15:19:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 17, 15, 19)
```

You can replace the first argument with the date you want to parse. The second argument is a format string to describe what your date looks like: you can learn about these [here](http://strftime.org/).